# Installing PhantomJS with Homebrew Issue

Tags: installation, phantomjs, homebrew

I'm installing PhantomJS with Homebrew, but the process seems to get stuck. I've waited 10 minutes while it was supposed to be patching but nothing happens (except for overclocking my CPU).

Is there a verbose install for homebrew?

```
$ brew install phantomjs 
Warning: Your Xcode (5.0) is outdated Please update to Xcode 5.0.1. Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

==> Downloading https://phantomjs.googlecode.com/files/phantomjs-1.9.2-source.zip 
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/phantomjs-1.9.2.zip

==> Patching  
patching file src/qt/src/gui/kernel/qt_cocoa_helpers_mac_p.h
==> ./build.sh --confirm --qt-config -no-3dnow
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you upgrade to Mavericks? Same issue, I think this is related to this.

Comment: Yup I did. Any luck troubleshooting?

Comment: So I updated my XCode to latest one that was released, installed the Mavericks command line tools, then did `brew update && brew install phantomjs` -- here was a similar issue that I found related: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/23491

Comment: Thanks! Updating helped, and it seems that they added bottles which sped up the install.

Comment: @ElijahMurray did you able to sort this out? I am having same issue!

Comment: @Volatil3 Updating XCode definitely helped. The other thing is, the install process really does take awhile. I forget how long I waited, but it was a go-make-yourself-a-sandwich-and-have-a-nap length.

Comment: I rather installed it via `npm` with ease since npm module does not install qt thing